# using angular2 with sharepoint framework

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I searched and implement some kind of tricks each time welcome diffirent errors based on same thing. The thing when it comes to bootstrapping webparts more than one times in same page(angular2 bootstraps only the first one).
[this](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-angular/) makes it clear;

> Comparing to Angular v1.x, Angular 2 uses a different mechanism for
>   bootstrapping applications. While using Angular 2 for building
>   Client-Side Web Parts seems to be working at first, if you would add
>   multiple instances of the same Web Part to the page, only the first
>   one would be bootstrapped.

angular2 not fit with SPFx its obvious ok but instead of asking them one by one, I want to ask if there is anyone know how to use(used) angular2 with SPFx. this probably help others trying to figure it out.